# Bash Profile Variables

Tags: bash

I apologize before-hand, not as knowledgable about bash files as I'd like.

I am using Cygwin. I have a bash_profile that I save my variables to so I can execute them later. I also have it where it references my bash_rc file. Here is my code.

```
if [ -f "${HOME}/.bashrc" ] ; then
    source "${HOME}/.bashrc"
fi

export TOSROOT="X/Y/Z"
```

Now when I save the file and close, I go back into Cygwin and do

```
echo $TOSROOT #nothing
```

It is empty. Any help on why the bash_profile/rc etc are not working? Why I can't use the variables.

Note -- I can type inside the command line

```
export TOSROOT="/X/Y/Z"

echo $TOSROOT #X/Y/Z
```

And it works.

```
PS4=':$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO+' bash -x -i #this returns

::3+PS4=':$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO+'
::3+bash -x -i
:/etc/bash.bashrc:21+[[ -z '' ]]
:/etc/bash.bashrc:21+CYG_SYS_BASHRC=1
:/etc/bash.bashrc:24+[[ himBH !- *i* ]]
:/etc/bash.bashrc:27+PS1='\[\e]0;\w\a]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\n\$ '
:/home/tdyuser/.bashrc:27+[[ himxBH != *i* ]]
```

Comment: There are several typos in your post. Hopefully they're not also in the real code? `"${HOME/.bashrc"` needs to be `"$HOME/.bashrc"` or `"${HOME}/.bashrc"`; `sourch` needs to be `source`; the string with the name of the file to be sourced needs closing quotes.

Comment: Anyhow, to trace what actually gets executed during shell startup, run `PS4=':$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO+' bash -x -l -i` (all on one line, no newline between the `PS4` assignment and the `bash` invocation) and you can see which dotfiles get run and what they're doing.

Comment: This is continuity I got, just trying to figure out why it's not running. I fixed those errors, and no, there were not on the actual code.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. You should try asking on [su].

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the xtrace log, collected as described above.

Comment: I wish I could. Not information I am allowed to hand out. Is there something you can help me look for? I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: Build a [mcve] -- that is to say, back up your original dotfiles, recreate the problem with the shortest possible code, and include both (1) the subset of code you found to be absolutely necessary for the problem's recreation, and (2) the xtrace logs from *that*. If you can't produce the problem with only code included in your question itself included in the runtime path, then how can we be expected to answer it with only that same content?

Comment: See also the "Tricks for Trimming" section at http://sscce.org/ for general guidance on coming up with the shortest possible reproducer for an issue.

Comment: ...that said, if you're using the PS4 I provided above, the logs will tell you which (if any) lines of your `.bashrc` and your `.bash_profile` are being executed, so if you're looking for places to start... well, that would be a good one, to be sure the `TOSROOT` is actually being set.

Comment: BTW, keep in mind that `.bash_profile` runs on login shells, *not* non-login interactive shells. Depending on your OS (and how it decides which shells to invoke as login shells -- MacOS, for instance, creates a login shell when opening a new terminal inside an existing session; many traditional UNIXen didn't/don't), this may means you need to log all the way out and back in, not just start a new terminal window. (By contrast, `.bashrc` is supposed to run for every interactive shell).

Comment: I'm using Cygwin, so I can exit Cygwin completely and log back in and it does not associate.

Comment: ...to emulate the invocation flow for a non-login interactive shell, just leave out the `-l` argument above, making it `PS4=':$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO+' bash -x -i`

Comment: ...so, even if you can't post the whole log, and if you're not willing to build a trimmed version of your dotfiles such that you *can* post a log -- for which of those invocations, if any, does the log actually include the TOSROOT assignment?

Comment: No it does not, got permission to post. One moment

Comment: So, `-x -i` isn't including `.bash_profile` and is just going straight to `.bashrc`, as we'd expect. How about `-x -l -i`, so we see what a login shell does?

Comment: That is a much longer list. haha. And the computer I am using does not have access to the internet so I am typing everything out. This one might takea bit lol

Comment: There is nothing printing out in reference to bash_profile tho

Comment: Wait, you mean `-x -l -i` doesn't include any reference to `.bash_profile`? *That's* interesting. Is there any `.profile` at all?

Comment: So how would I use variables from within bash_profile in this case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177818/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-impression7vx).

Answer (score 0):

The `~/.profile`, `/etc/profile`, `~/.bash_rc` and `/etc/bashrc` are only processed when a shell is invoked.  If you've made changed, exit your current shell session and start a new one.

Comment: Yea, I can open/close/restart etc. Nothing happens.